# Why is this interface not correctly released when the method is exited?

Tags: delphi, reference-counting, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My current code looks like this:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class
  public
    Events: TList<TProc>;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TTracingInterfacedObject = class(TInterfacedObject)
  public
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  end;

  ISharedPtr<T> = interface
    ['{CC9EE6C5-F07B-40E5-B05D-2DFDBD3404A1}']
    function Get: T;
    function GetRefCount: Integer;
  end;

  ICatalog = interface
    ['{F421BBA8-8DA3-47EE-ADB9-DED26747472E}']
    function GetView: ISharedPtr<TForm1>;
    property View: ISharedPtr<TForm1> read GetView;
  end;

  ITree = interface
    ['{A1E2F71B-124B-48DB-B038-5F90AC5BE94B}']
    function GetId: TGUID;
    property Id: TGUID read GetId;
  end;

  TSharedPtr<T: class> = class(TTracingInterfacedObject, ISharedPtr<T>)
  private
    FObject: T;
  public
    constructor Create(const AObject: T);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function GetRefCount: Integer;
    function Get: T;
  end;

  TCatalog = class(TTracingInterfacedObject, ICatalog)
  private
    FView: ISharedPtr<TForm1>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function GetView: ISharedPtr<TForm1>;
  end;

  TTree = class(TTracingInterfacedObject, ITree)
  private
    FView: ISharedPtr<TForm1>;
  public
    constructor Create(const AView: ISharedPtr<TForm1>);
    function GetId: TGUID;
  end;

function TTracingInterfacedObject._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(ClassName + '._AddRef'));
  Result := inherited _AddRef;
end;

function TTracingInterfacedObject._Release: Integer;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(ClassName + '._Release'));
  Result := inherited _Release;
end;

constructor TForm1.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  Events := TList<TProc>.Create;
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  Events.Free;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TSharedPtr<T>.Create(const AObject: T);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FObject := AObject;
end;

destructor TSharedPtr<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FObject.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TSharedPtr<T>.Get: T;
begin
  Result := FObject;
end;

function TSharedPtr<T>.GetRefCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FRefCount;
end;

constructor TCatalog.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FView := TSharedPtr<TForm1>.Create(TForm1.Create) as ISharedPtr<TForm1>;
end;

function TCatalog.GetView: ISharedPtr<TForm1>;
begin
  Result := FView;
end;

constructor TTree.Create(const AView: ISharedPtr<TForm1>);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FView := AView;
end;

function TTree.GetId: TGUID;
begin
  Result := TGUID.Empty;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  Catalog: ICatalog;
  Tree: ITree;
  Func: TFunc<TGUID>;
  Events: TList<TProc>;
  Event: TProc;
begin
  Catalog := TCatalog.Create as ICatalog;

  Events := Catalog.View.Get.Events;

  Event := procedure
    begin
    end;

  Events.Add(Event);

  Tree := TTree.Create(Catalog.View) as ITree;

  Func := function: TGUID
    begin
      Result := Tree.Id;
    end;
end;

begin
  Main;

end.
```

I have set a breakpoint at the final `end.` of the application.

The event log looks like this at that point:

```
Debug Output: TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._AddRef Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TCatalog._AddRef Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._AddRef Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._AddRef Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._AddRef Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TTree._AddRef Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._Release Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._Release Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TCatalog._Release Process Project1.exe (3456)
Debug Output: TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._Release Process Project1.exe (3456)
Source Breakpoint at $0047F675: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\ViewFail\Project1.dpr line 168. Process Project1.exe (3456)
```

So:

- Catalog is _AddRefed once and _Released once which is fine.
- Tree is _AddRefed once and never _Released which is not what I expected.
- Catalog.View is _AddRefed four times and _Released only three times which is also not what I expected.

Why does this happen? Is there a reference cycle somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: Is it not possible to cut this down into something minimal, something with no UI, in a single dpr file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried, but if I remove any more code the problem goes away.

Comment: I reworked it a bit more and you can now just throw it into an empty console application project. To see the problem you have to set a breakpoint at the end of the program (as described in the question).

Comment: Main problem is that your Form has two owners - Application and SharedPtr. Because of anonymous method variable capture Application releases the form and leaves SharedPtr with dangling reference. In essence your Form is released twice.

Comment: Now, you could fix immediate problems in that code, but don't. That code is beyond horrible. Trust me, you don't want to use something like that in the production ;)

Comment: Another tip. When debugging, don't debug reference counts - this will tell you absolutely nothing. Put your logging information in destructors and it will be immediately obvious what is being released multiple times or in wrong order.

Comment: Except that this TForm1 class is not derived by TForm or TComponent in the reduced example is it stands now.

Comment: My problem is that the TForm1 object is not released by the time the `Main` method is exited. It is kept alive for too long as if there was some global state somewhere that I can't see.

Comment: The TTree is not released, so the shared ptr it holds is not released either. That much is sure.

Comment: I can't really point a finger on it yet, but ISTM that your problem is the View function. Is your "SharedPtr" really a pointer that can be shared and simply returned by a function?

Comment: When I comment out Event := procedure.. I get TTree released and four TSharedPtr<Project1.TForm1>._Release. Compiler magic?

Comment: Yes, I found that out too. Event is implemented as an interface, and it keeps a reference to the tree too. So in a way, you seem to have a circular reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a reference cycle in your code. It is created through anonymous method variable capture mechanism.

Anonymous methods are backed by reference counted, compiler generated class. Any variables captured by anonymous method are stored as fields in the same class. Compiler instantiates instance of that class and keeps it alive as long as anonymous method is in scope.

Now, above facts would not be enough to create cycle. But same instance (same class) will be used to back up all anonymous methods within some routine.

Translated to your code:

- `TForm1` holds `Events`
- `Catalog` holds `TForm1`
- `Tree` holds `TForm1`

No cycles there - `Tree` does not reference `Catalog`, nor `Catalog` references `Tree`

But, when you look at your `Main` procedure things change.

Anonymous methods in `Main` will be backed by hidden object instance - so let's see what will be there:

- First anonymous method
- Second anonymous method
- `Tree` - captured by second anonymous method

Still no visible cycles - but, then you add first anonymous method `Event` to the `Events` list that is held by `Tree`. In order to keep that method alive the whole backing object will be kept alive too.

```
Anonymous method object -> Event 
                        -> Tree -> Events -> Event -> Anonymous method object
```

To break that cycle you have to clear some references. For instance set `Tree` to `nil` somewhere in `Main`.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that there is only one object for all the the anonymous methods? It would certainly explain the behaviour we are seeing here.

Comment: Not that I know of. But this is kind of implied by the design. If you have two methods that capture same variable they would need to be backed up by same class - so that is the reasoning behind that effect.